# Check current time lies in two times in java

Tags: java, android, time

I am trying to check whether current time is between *Start Time* and *End time*. But my method always return false:

**from = "5:10:00";
to = "10:10:00"**

---

```
private boolean isTimeBetweenTwoTime(String from, String to) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("H:mm:ss");

    Date date_from = formatter.parse(from);
    Date date_to = formatter.parse(to);

    Time startTime = new Time(date_from.getTime());
    Time endTime = new Time(date_to.getTime());

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    Time now = new Time(c.getTimeInMillis());

    if (now.before(endTime) && now.after(startTime)) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Yes time between");
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it with a hard coded `now` time?

Comment: Of course this is `false`. Just because the class `java.sql.Time` represents a time, it doesn't mean that the underlying `java.util.Date` class will lose its date information. So `now` is _way_ after `endTime`, since 2016 > 1970.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that when you do this

```
Date date_from = formatter.parse(from);
Date date_to = formatter.parse(to);
```

and the formatter is so defined:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("H:mm:ss");
```

then is for  the java api relevant only the time, but date objects hold  more than time info, they hold too year, month, etc and those are getting initalize to a epoch [UNIXTime](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unixzeit)

so the initial dates you are creating are

> Thu Jan 01 05:10:00 CET 1970 and Thu Jan 01 10:10:00 CET 1970

so asking if today/right now (22th june 2016) is between those dates will NEVER return true...

on the other hand you conditions look inverted and as final tip you dont need SQL-Classes for the calculation, just with date objects you will get it pretty good

## Example:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    String from = "5:10:00";
    String to = "10:10:00";
    String n = "08:10:00";
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    Date date_from = formatter.parse(from);
    Date date_to = formatter.parse(to);
    Date dateNow = formatter.parse(n);
    if (date_from.before(dateNow) && date_to.after(dateNow)) {
        System.out.println("Yes time between");
    }
    }
```

Comment: As I am dealing with only time constraint, so example worked for me perfectly. I have modified a bit to add current time in `n` variable.

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

You are using old outmoded classes. They have been supplanted by the java.time classes built into Java 8 and later. Mush of the functionality has been back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in ThreeTen-Backport and further adapted to Android in ThreeTenABP.

### `LocalTime`

The [`LocalTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) class actually truly represents a time-of-day only value, unlike the `java.sql.Time` and `java.util.Date` classes seen in the Question.

```
LocalTime start = LocalTime.of( 5 , 10 );
LocalTime stop = LocalTime.of( 10 , 0 );
```

### Time zone

Determining the current time requires a time zone. For any given moment the time varies around the globe by time zone.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalTime now = LocalTime.now( zoneId );
```

### Compare

Compare by calling `equals`, isAfter, or isBefore. We use the Half-open approach here as is common in date-time work where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*.

```
 Boolean isNowInRange = ( ! now.isBefore( start ) ) && now.isBefore( stop ) ;
```

Answer (score -3):

Check this

Pass your dates to method

```
public static int isValidDate(String start,String end){
        int valid=0;
        DateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:MM:SS");
        Date d1 = null;
        Date d2 = null;
        Date d3 = null;
        Calendar curDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat dfcurDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:MM:SS");
        String datecurrent = dfcurDate.format(curDate.getTime());
        try {
            d1 = formatter1.parse(datecurrent);
            d2 = new Date(Long.parseLong(end));
            d3 = new Date(Long.parseLong(start));
            System.out.println(d1.after(d3) && d1.before(d2));
            if (d1.after(d3) && d1.before(d2)) {
                valid=1;
           } } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return valid;
    }
```

if return 1--Current